# Regular expression for a date range

Tags: regex, grep, range

If I have a directory structure like this

```
yyyy/dd/mm/<files>
```

Is there a way to grep for a string in all files in a given time frame using a regex? For example, I have a time frame: 2010/12/25 - 2011/01/01, I need to grep all files in directories corresponding to dates from 25th december to jan 1st

If I am doing this programmatically, is it better to iterate over the date range and grep files in each yyyy/dd/mm directory than to use a regex to do this? Or would it not make a difference?

Comment: Personally I'd just iterate. It *might* be possible to do this with a regex but it would be pretty complex. Cue Jamie Zawinsky quote: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.'

Comment: @harithski Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem. If you would like I can start a question as well.

Comment: I resorted to using a for loop.

Answer (score 17):

In your case, it's simple enough:

```
\b(?:2010/12/(?:3[01]|2[5-9])|2011/01/01)\b
```

will match a string that contains a date in the range you specified. But generally, regexes are not a good fit for matching date ranges. It's always a possibility, but rarely a good one.

For example, for the range 2003/04/25-2011/04/04, you get

```
\b(?:
2003/04/(?:30|2[5-9])|
2003/(?:(?:0[69]|11)/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])|(?:0[578]|1[02])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]))|
2011/04/0[1-4]|2011/(?:02/(?:[12][0-9]|0[1-9])|0[13]/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]))|
(?:2010|200[4-9])/(?:02/(?:[12][0-9]|0[1-9])|(?:0[469]|11)/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])|(?:0[13578]|1[02])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9]))
)\b
```

If I had to do something like this (and couldn't use the creation dates in the file attributes), I would either use RegexMagic (to create the date range regex) and PowerGREP (to do the grepping) if it's a one-time job, but these are only available on Windows. If I had to do this more often, I'd write a small Python script that walks through my directory tree, parses the date for each directory, checks if it's in range, and then looks at the files in that directory.

Comment: Oh boy! What have I gotten into.

Performance wise, would it make a difference if I did `grep string <regex matching a set of files>` Vs. `for date in <range of dates>: do grep string $date` ?

Comment: No idea, I don't know `grep`. I guess the former would be faster, but I can't say for sure. Just to check the obvious: Can't you just iterate over all the files and look at the file creation dates instead of grepping their paths?

Comment: Things are more complicated than that. The file in each date directory isn't when the file is actually created.

Comment: old question I know, but my two cents (or "pence") would be that it's almost certainly not "worth it" trying to do this with RegEx... just accept the for / foreach loop and get on with your life. Only type of edge case I can see if perhaps if you were working on some extremely high-end high-performance system (like maybe in banking industry) where every single micro second counted... and even then it would be sensible to do some performance testing of the code with each solution before deciding which to use - you might find the loop actually faster anyway. Regex not designed for date ranges.