# Regex: expression matching a valid date but with minimum and maximum dates

Tags: regex, date

I found this to validate a date in dd/MM/YYYY:

```
^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$
```

How do I set minimum/maximum dates ?

Comment: What language are you using?  Number comparison is something best left out of RegEx.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I'm using javascript (maskedinput.js) [click here to see page](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: Regular expressions have no notion of dates, your expression would get very complex due to the different length of months (28, 30 and 31 days) and handling leap years (let alone handling different locales). You would be better off parsing a valid date and then checking that the date is in the valid range using JavaScript proper.

Comment: To illustrate @michielvoo's point, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839987/regular-expression-for-a-date-range/6840085#6840085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming languages(such as`java`, `C#`, `python`, etc) have `date/time/datetime` type.
`date` can be created via constructor if you supply valid arguments.
If not, it will product `exception` which can be captured(usually `try...catch` statement).
It's hard to validate `29/2/2012` and `29/2/2013` using `regex`.
But it's easy with the help of `date` type of the language.

```
$ python
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime('29/2/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=29, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=60, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.strptime('29/2/2013', '%d/%m/%Y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/_strptime.py", line 482, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/_strptime.py", line 459, in _strptime
    datetime_date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use that plugin, at least you know you'll have a valid date from a formatting standpoint.  Then it's the job of JavaScript to parse the date and determine all of the rules.

This [function](http://jsfiddle.net/uLnKe/) isn't *complete*, so if anyone adds on to it: press the update button and drop the link here.  If it's more complete I'll update this post.

I couldn't imagine doing real validation of a date in RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing dates you can use [`date.js`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) too.

HTH