# How to specify regex to pick up files dated 2019-02-20 onwards?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to fetch some file having the format

```
user_registrations.log.2019-03-20_04.
```

have specified file patter like

```
"user_registrations.log." + "[._a-zA-Z0-9]*"
```

I need the files dated 2019-02-20th on wards till 2019-03-20.

How do I specify this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839987/regular-expression-for-a-date-range)

Comment: It is far better that you extract that part of the filenames and confirm that it is a valid date (by attempting to create a Date object); then you can perform date arithmetic based on its value.

Answer (score 3):

```
user_registrations.log.2019-0(2-2\d|3-[0,1]\d|3-20)_\d+
```

gives the matchig of:

[image]

Comment: Your regex is matching for example `user_registrations.log.2019-02-29_04.` (EDIT: this day does not exist in calendar)

Comment: Yes, and it also mathcing the user_registrations.log.2019-03-00_04. But will the files with such names be ever created?

Answer (score 1):

In your specified case you could use this:

```
user_registrations.log.((2019-02-2[0-8])|(2019-03-((0[1-9]|1[0-9])|(20))))
```

Explanation:

- `(2019-02-2[0-8])` all days of February (2019 is not leap)
- `|` means OR
- `(2019-03-((0[1-9]|1[0-9])|(20)))` for desired days of March. In this part of regex there are another ORs for days from 01 to 19 OR just for 2019-03-20, excluding for example 2019-03-00 which is not a proper date.

Answer (score 0):

I used a diff approach.
Fetch all files and extract the date from the file Name, then convert it to milliseconds.
Compare this with the expected start and end date in Milliseconds.