# How to filter a range of dates in emeditor

Tags: emeditor

How can i use Advanced Filter to extract a range of dates from a Column (eg: Btw 25/09/2021 & 27/09/2021) in Emeditor?

Comment: Can you please write an example?

Comment: NAME DATE
A 20/07/2021
S 21/07/2021
H 22/07/2021
DFS 23/07/2021
E 24/07/2021
DFS 25/07/2021
H 26/07/2021
HSH 27/07/2021
DFG 28/07/2021
FE 29/07/2021
EE 30/07/2021
RESULT EXTRACTED DATES 
NAME DATE
DFS 23/07/2021
E 24/07/2021
DFS 25/07/2021
H 26/07/2021

Comment: If i want to extract dates in a column that is greater or less than 23/07/2021. OR extract dates in a column that is between a range of dates. eg. From 23/07/2021 to 30/07/2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use multiple regular expressions combined with Logical Disjunction (`OR`) to filter a range of dates.

For example, if you want to extract dates from `23/07/2021` through `30/07/2021`, you can use:

`2[3-9]/07/2021` **OR** `30/07/2021`

[image: EmEditor - Advanced Filter]

There are some [articles of regular expressions for a range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839987/regular-expression-for-a-date-range):

However, the advantage of using EmEditor is that you can define several regular expressions and combine them using Logical Disjunction (`OR`), so that search expressions can be simplified.

It is possible that EmEditor might support date ranges natively in future versions.

**Updates:**
[v21.2.901](https://www.emeditor.com/forums/topic/emeditor-v21-3-beta-1-21-3-901/) (and later) supports date ranges natively.

Comment: Thank you so much  Yukuta! Much appreciated

Comment: BUT CAN I USE 'GREATER THAN' OR 'LESS THAN' IN THESE DATE SENARIOS?

Comment: You'll just need to increment or decrement the starting or ending dates.