# How to filter values in a date range when the exact timestamps are not entered in the log

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to takes value counts in a given date range from a log file. My log file is looks like this.

```
values.log 

2022-01-01-10:01 AAA-passed
2022-01-01-11:05 AAA-passed
2022-01-01-12:01 AAA-passed
2022-01-01-13:05 AAA-passed
2022-01-02-12:01 AAA-failed
2022-01-03-13:05 AAA-failed
```

I have tried the following method to take the value counts in the given time range.

```
t1='2022-01-01-10:01'
t2='2022-01-03-13:05'

pass=$(awk '/^'$t1.*'/,/'$t2.*'/' values.log | grep -w "AAA-passed" | wc -l)
echo $pass
```

This method works only if exact timestamps have been entered in the log file. But if we give a time range which are not entered in the log file, this method does not work and not gives the answer,

for an example if we give

```
    t1='2022-01-01-10:00'
    t2='2022-01-03-14:00'
```

this not gives any answer, because these exact values for t1 and t2 are not entered in the log file. I tried lot of other methods also but nothing worked for me. Can someone help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance..!

---

Edit -

I found a relevant answer for this,

```
awk -v 'start=2018-04-12 14:44:00.000' -v end='2018-04-12 14:45:00.000' '
   /^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} / {
     inrange = $0 >= start && $0 <= end
   }
   inrange' < your-file
```

This method work for me, but I dont hard code values for t1 and t2

```
t1=$(date -d "${dtd} -7 days" +'%Y-%m-%d-%R')
t2=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%R')

Result time format - 2022-07-05-12:15
Required time format - 2018-04-12 14:44:00.000
```

so how can I edit the above expressions to get the date time in required time format.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839987/regular-expression-for-a-date-range)

Comment: using mktime `match($0,/^(....)-(..)-(..)-(..):(..)/,a)&&mktime("2022 01 01 10 00 00")<(t=mktime(a[1]" "a[2
]" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" 00"))&&t<mktime("2022 01 03 14 00 00")`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul you should mention that requires GNU awk for time functions and the 3rd arg to `match()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Fravadona answered the question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72868854/1745001) so you should accept their answer but this is too long to add as a comment and requires formatting so here it is - FYI in addition to your timestamp comparison, you don't need pipes to grep and wc when you're using awk:

```
t1='2022-01-01-10:01'
t2='2022-01-03-13:05'

pass=$(
    awk -v beg="$t1" -v end="$t2" '
        (beg <= $1) && ($1 <= end) && /AAA-passed/ { cnt++ }
        END { print cnt+0 }
    ' values.log
)
echo "$pass"
```

Comment: this method perfectly worked with my scenario, and this helped me to maintain a common approach in different places :)

Comment: You should accept [@Fravadona's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72868854/1745001) instead of mine as they were the first to answer the question you asked, I just added some additional information to help with the rest of your script.

Answer (score 4):

Your timestamp format is `YYYY-mm-dd-HH:MM` so you can directly use string comparisons:

```bash
t1=2022-01-01-10:01
t2=2022-01-03-13:05

awk -v start="$t1" -v end="$t2" 'start <= $1 && $1 <= end' values.log
```